# Flutter Firebase query not returning any data

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to get data from flutter firestore using the following query. But it returns me noting, when i remove the where query then the code works properly

[image].

```
await db
  .collection('captured_data')
  .where('Name', isEqualTo: 'Ali Hussain')
  .get()
  .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) async {
  i++;

  print(doc["Name"]);
  Invoice.items.add(
    InvoiceItem(
        Name: doc["Name"],
        date: doc["Time"],
        sleep: doc["Sleep"],
        vehicle: doc["Vehicle Name"],
        age: doc["Age"],
        blinks: doc["Blinks"],
        vehicle_speed: doc["Vehicle Speed"],
        yawn: doc["Yawn"]),
  );

  if (i == querySnapshot.size) {
    final pdfFile =
        await PdfInvoiceApi.generate(invoice);

    PdfApi.openFile(pdfFile);
  }
```

Comment: The document in the screenshot doesn't match the query here `.where('Name', isEqualTo: 'Ali Hussain')`, so won't be returned as part of this query.

Comment: The screenshot is of another document in the same collection, but "Name: Ali Hussain" is also present in other document.

Comment: So please update your question (there's an edit link right under it) to show the document that you expect this query to return.